# Get/fetch data from database without refresh the page

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json, data-binding

Hi I'd like some help please. I'm currently learning Ajax and Json so I don't have much experience on it.

I have followed this [tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G_7oYeNU_3g) in order to fetch the data without page refresh, but I'm having some concerns on it.

The script works fine, the only problem I found is that if I hit refresh it takes a lot of time (about 5-10 seconds)to load the content again.
In Firebug I can see in the Console that it is continiously binding as it's sending requests all time.
Here's the code
HTML

```
<div class="ajax_results">
    <ul id="results"></ul>
</div>
```

PHP script

```
$query = "SELECT `img_id`, `image_name`, `title` FROM `images` ORDER BY `img_id` DESC LIMIT 5 ";
$run = mysqli_query($connection, $query) or die(mysqli_error($connection));

$json = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($run, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    array_push($json, array('image_name' => $row['image_name'],
                            'title' => $row['title']));
}
echo json_encode(array("json" => $json));
```

and the JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    refresh();
});

function refresh() {
    setTimeout(function() { 
        update_content(); 
        refresh();
    }, 200);
}

function update_content() {
    $.getJSON("fetch_data.php", function(data) {
        $("ul#results").empty();
        $.each(data.json, function() {
            $("ul#results").append("<li><img src=\"img/uploads/"+this['image_name']+"\" /><br />"+this['title']+"</li>");
        });
    });
}
```

Is this a problem?? Can I improve somehow the code?? Any help would be appreciated

To give some extra feedback. If the $.getJSON is directly placed in $(document).ready(function() the content loads more quickly, but if any updates occured eg in the title won't show without refreshing the page.  What I actually want to achieve is load the content and if any changes happened to show them without refreshing the page.

Comment: The issue is the interval in setTimeout, 200 milliseconds is an extremely small amount of time! .2 of a second

Comment: you mean I have to put something greater than this??

Comment: Personally I would yes! There's 1000 milliseconds in one second, just for reference. Imagine it takes about 100 milliseconds just for the ajax request to complete, then there's the time taken to load the images into the browser, 200 miliiseconds later it's going to fire off the request again whether or not the previous request has finished.

Comment: It might be worth moving the setTimeout into the update_content() function, so that the images have loaded and the ajax request has finished, and then fire it off again.

Comment: I switched it to 1000 milliseconds and it loads more quickly indeed!
Is it possible to do this with a better way, eg to have only one request instead of infinate?

Comment: Yes, simply call the function once, and don't fire off the refresh function, which is what is making it repeat

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand you. Could you be more thorough or give me an example of this??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's another approach to the issue

```
$(function() {
    update_content();
});

function update_content() {
    $.getJSON("fetch_data.php", function(data) {
        $("ul#results").empty();
        $.each(data.json, function() {
            $("ul#results").append("<li><img src=\"img/uploads/"+this['image_name']+"\" /><br />"+this['title']+"</li>");
        });
        setTimeout(function(){
            update_content();
        }, 1000);
    });
}
```

Here I've moved the setTimeout call into the update_content() function, and increased the timeout to give the browser a bit more breathing room, personally I wouldn't call this every second but it's just an example, I'd probably go with 10 seconds or even longer.

If you don't want it to fire off repeatedly remove the entire setTimeout block.

```
$(function() {
    update_content();
});

function update_content() {
    $.getJSON("fetch_data.php", function(data) {
        $("ul#results").empty();
        $.each(data.json, function() {
            $("ul#results").append("<li><img src=\"img/uploads/"+this['image_name']+"\" /><br />"+this['title']+"</li>");
        });
    });
}
```