# php html dynamically add to end of list items

Tags: php, list

I have some data on the server side in a database like Person Info.

I'd like to do the following when the user first views the page: show e.g 3 person info on list like placement.

I can do this by write query for read from database and write "for" in php 
and write html code and echo to fill 3 list item.

Next now I need add a link like "more persons" below this tree output and when user clicks this link PHP will show other Persons Info at the end of previous 3 person info without refresh page or redirecting.

How can I do that?

Comment: the short answer is `ajax` there are lots of tutorials out there for this

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get/fetch data from database without refresh the page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18608697/get-fetch-data-from-database-without-refresh-the-page)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an ajax job, you will need to pass the last id of the last person and get the next lot. Anyway ajax - so look into jquery - should make it an easier job.

Comment: thanks for your answer, i newbie in php coding, i must go to how ajax can help me. i google it now. thanks

Answer (score 0):

What you need to use is ajax. I will suggest using jquery for ajax because it will let you get started quickly.

https://learn.jquery.com/ajax/

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for your answer, i newbie in php coding, i must go to how ajax can help me. i google it now. thanks

Comment: Ajax
Traditionally webpages required reloading to update their content.